# How does node-imagemagick compare to node-gm?

Tags: javascript, image, node.js

I want to resize photos, crop photos, etc. That's all.

But I need to be able to deal with PNG's and transparent png's.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well they both need some other software installed on your OS (be it GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick), but [node-gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) has a nicer api, for example:

```
// crazytown
gm('/path/to/my/img.jpg')
.flip()
.magnify()
.rotate('green', 45)
.blur(7, 3)
.crop(300, 300, 150, 130)
.edge(3)
.write('/path/to/crazy.jpg', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('crazytown has arrived');
})
```

The other module, [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick), has 4-5 functions, and for the rest you can pass in options.

In terms of performance you should compare ImageMagick with GraphicsMagick, some useful links here:

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/benchmarks.html 
http://www.admon.org/graphicsmagick-vs-imagemagick/ 
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=886010

Also you should know that GraphicsMagick is derived from ImageMagick.

Comment: If I don't care about performance, but I want more "features", which one should I pick? Also, I'm worried because node-gm seems to have a less community (but highly maintained) vs imagemagick that hasn't changed since May.

Comment: You should pick node-gm, it's more maintained, has a better API and it's more efficient. In terms of 'features' I think you can do just fine with both. Last but not least, since Flickr and Etsy use GraphicsMagick, I would use node-gm :)

Comment: node-imagemagick no longer seems to be maintained and will be totally broken with node >= 0.7. Do not use.

Comment: Node 0.7.x is unstable, the last stable version is 0.6.x. Odd versions are unstable.

Comment: I'd recommend to use the node-gm since the imagemagick module is somehow unsupported for long, besides, after checking it around, GraphicsMagick seems to have more feature so its nothing to lose.

Comment: On top of all this, since version 1.x of node-gm, you can use ImageMagick if you need to (see the README).

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer speed, there's a faster (native addon) alternative.

https://npmjs.org/package/imagemagick-native